# An angular-material-multilevel-menu for Angular 6?

Tags: angular6, sidenav

I have tried to achieve a multilevel sidenav and I found this that meets my requirements:

[angular-material-multilevel-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-multilevel-menu)

[Demo](https://jmouriz.github.io/angular-material-multilevel-menu/demo/demo.html#!/demo/readme) - Note the accordion type

Unfortunately this is created for AngularJS (1.0?), which seems to not work in Angular 6.

My questions are:

1. Is there any other multilevel sidenav component for Angular 6? Have note found any similar on Google that works.
2. Is it possible to "upgrade" this Angular 1.0 menu to Angular 6? How?
3. Is there any simple instructions or courses to build your own multilevel side nav? There are many instructions for one-level, but I have found none multi-level.

Comment: Hello. Your questions 1 and 3 don't fit in stack overflow, since they are about finding tools and tutorials. See the [topic list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). For the second, sure it is, but you'll probably need to perform many major changes in the [source code](https://github.com/jmouriz/angular-material-multilevel-menu). Too broad to be covered by a single answer here...

Comment: @Xtreme Biker I will post an example that I found by accident. Hope you can give some clues on my remaining issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if you are still looking for angular-material-multilevel-menu but I have found one made by ShankyTiwari.
Here is the link for [GitHub](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu) and the link for the [demo](http://plugins.codershood.info/#/plugins/ngmm-plugin).

Very easy to use and to implement. For example, I implemented it in a sidebar because it does not exist with Angular material.
If not an alternative would be PrimeNG as @Dino said.

Comment: Still looking. I have managed to get the same look as ShankyTiwari by standard modules. But still limited success setting backgrund colors. Can you control the background / selected colors in his module?

Comment: Yes you can if you set up the configuration. Have a look at the API section on GitHub https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu#api

Comment: Thanks a lot  @PierBJX, This link is very useful and exactly meet my requirement..

Comment: This is not working on IE 11: https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu/issues/87

Comment: Hi @Sampath, IDK if you are using something else, but just in case if you again need to create a Multilevel list or people who are reading this question for the first time, then you can use it in IE11 as well 

The issue [#87](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu/issues/87) is fixed now.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, @Shanky Ok sure! Yes, I do not use it. But I hope someone will get the benefit of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Angular Material 6.0 doesn't come with multilevel menu out of the box. You would have to create it on your own. It would be a combination of [Nested Menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples), and [Side Nav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview).

And to answer your first question, I'd suggest you to take a look at [PrimeNG's Panel Menu](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/panelmenu). It does exactly what you need and with some little effort, you'll also be able to change it's design into Material like. (I did it with some PrimeNG components, so I can confirm that it works.

> Please take in consideration that PrimeNG 6.0.0 is currently in
>   [Alpha-2 version](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6-0-0-alpha-2-released/).

Comment: As I interpret this, is Nested Menus popping up at right, but there is a property "direction: Direction". Do you have any examples of expanding second level below the first level? And I cannot find any examples of PrimNG than "SLIDEmenu" which is nice but not my first goal.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Demo]

I found a PART of a solution.

[Here is a demo using "mat-expansion-panel"](http://94.237.25.207/)

There are still some issues that must be solved.

1. The shadow and offset of the Expansion Level
2. The shutdown instead of stay selected
3. Better way to do this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you add the source for this

Comment: No. I have abandon Angular and have no memory of how I did. Now I use Golang http://94.237.25.207:8080

Answer (score 3):

I was looking to create multi-level menus with native angular material but still under development by ng material team. So, I'd like to suggest to use [ng-material-multilevel-menu](http://plugins.codershood.info/#/plugins/ngmm-plugin) package for now by follow the below:

1. `npm install --save ng-material-multilevel-menu` or `yarn add --save ng-material-multilevel-menu`
2. Then import `NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule` by

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 
/* Import the module*/
import { NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule } from 'ng-material-multilevel-menu';
 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule // Import here
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. Call `<ng-material-multilevel-menu  [configuration]='config' [items]='appitems' (selectedItem)="selectedItem($event)"></ng-material-multilevel-menu>` in your html.
4. Finally, declare `appitems` for your list items and `config` object

```js
appitems = [
    {
        label: 'NPM',
        icon: 'favorite',
        link: 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-multilevel-menu',
        externalRedirect: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Item 1 (with Font awesome icon)',
        faIcon: 'fab fa-500px',
        items: [
            {
                label: 'Item 1.1',
                link: '/item-1-1',
                faIcon: 'fab fa-accusoft'
            },
            {
                label: 'Item 1.2',
                faIcon: 'fab fa-accessible-icon',
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'Item 1.2.1',
                        link: '/item-1-2-1',
                        faIcon: 'fas fa-allergies'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Item 1.2.2',
                        faIcon: 'fas fa-ambulance',
                        items: [
                            {
                                label: 'Item 1.2.2.1',
                                link: 'item-1-2-2-1',
                                faIcon: 'fas fa-anchor',
                                onSelected: function() {
                                    console.log('Item 1.2.2.1');
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'Item 2',
        icon: 'alarm',
        items: [
        {
            label: 'Item 2.1',
            link: '/item-2-1',
            icon: 'favorite'
        },
        {
            label: 'Item 2.2',
            link: '/item-2-2',
            icon: 'favorite_border'
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'Item 3',
        link: '/item-3',
        icon: 'offline_pin',
        onSelected: function() {
            console.log('Item 3');
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Item 4',
        link: '/item-4',
        icon: 'star_rate',
        hidden: true
    }
];

  config = {
    paddingAtStart: false,
    classname: 'my-custom-class',
    listBackgroundColor: '#fafafa',
    fontColor: 'rgb(8, 54, 71)',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    selectedListFontColor: 'red',
    interfaceWithRoute: true
  };
```

Note: `interfaceWithRoute`  will enable root item to be linkable if link property is available.